# iptables configuration on Windows Azure (CentOS 6.5) for endpoint load-balanced set

Tags: linux, iptables, postgresql, azure

I created 2 VMs (CentOS6.5) on Windows Azure for Postgresql database and HA cluster, everything works fine except when I set iptables service on, the endpoint load-balanced set  is down.

for security issue, I blocked all input access except trust domain and intranet.

```
:INPUT DROP [1:40] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:152]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s myTrustDomain.cloudapp.net -j ACCEPT
```

I'm pretty sure the problem comes from firewall because once I turn iptables service off, all client will be able to connect to port 5432. but I really need **load-balanced set endpoint** to switch node when one of them goes down in HA cluster.

Does anyone know how to configure firewall properly when I use load-balanced set endpoint?